# Programmatic Save button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, foursquare

I'm working on a site that will have more than one 'Save' button per page, and I need a callback for each one so that I can register in my own system that the user has completed the Save action. I thought I had figured out how to do this programmatically... but for each widget I create, when I try to add it to the DOM through the SDK, I get a "Cannot read property 'style' of null" error.

Here's my Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function () {
        window.___fourSq = {
            "uid": "31904528",
            "secure": true,
            "explicit": false,
            "onReady": function () {
                $('.fourSquareVenueId').each(function () {
                    var vid = $(this).val();
                    var widget = new fourSq.widget.SaveTo({
                        "vid": vid
                    });
                    var container = $(this).parent().find('.placeholder');
                    widget.replace(container);
                });
            }
        };
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = 'https://platform-s.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js';
        s.async = true;
        var ph = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        ph.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ph);
    })();
```

Basically, when the SDK is loaded, I go through and find all of my hidden inputs with the venue id in it, and there I try to create a 'Save' widget to replace an empty anchor tag I have as a place holder.

And here's a link to the screenshot of the error in the Chrome console:

http://gyazo.com/f011c25bb88181251e2820e748b41093.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the Foursquare documentation i'm using: 
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/widgets#programmatic-instantiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long shot, but did you change the prototype of the Array object ?

Comment: I got it, it's actually kind of obvious if you think about it. I was sending in a jQuery object, when foursquare's sdk wanted me to send it a DOM element. Changed the line setting the container variable to the following: var container = $(this).parent().find('a')[0];

Comment: Can this get edited to be a little clearer, or vnads can you post your comment as the solution? It took me a bit to figure it out as well, but your clue about returning the DOM element is what solved my issue as well. Not sure whether to upvote this, though, as it's not quite clear....